# Is there a way to force Google Chrome to open in full screen?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fullscreen

When I'm working just on my MacBook Pro,I like to keep as many apps as I can in Lion's full-screen mode.  One of these apps is Google Chrome.  However, Chrome doesn't remember that I want it to appear full screen after I quit it.  It always opens up in "windowed" mode.  Is there a way to force it to start in full screen?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you close the window or type Command+W before quitting?

Comment: No, I quit using Command+Q, without closing the window first.

Comment: Interesting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Google Chrome for Mac (14.0.835.202) is not correctly supporting this behavior, even when the System Preference to "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" is selected in the General Preferences pane (like the Mail app or Safari does). There is an open bug ticket on this issue with Google so at some point the "remember full screen state after close" should be resolved. Here is the bug report link:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94611

Comment: While disappointing - at least I know someone has reported it as a bug.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem BUT i think i found out how to make google chrome always open full screen. go to the wrench on the right hand side of the task bar when you have chrome open. go to settings, under the on start up section click "continue where i left off." BAM google chrome should now open full screen... well it does for me anyways. hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but everyone seems to want to mak a major deal out of this. The fix is VERY simple.
When Chrome opens in half screen or whatever, put the cursor at the very top right edge of the window. A double headed, diagonal arrow will appear. Drag it all the way to the right. Do the same with the left side. Close Chrome and reopen it. It will open full screen every time from that point forward.